# PHP Parse stdclass object

Tags: php, xml

I get the following output (var_dump) from an API call.  I need to obtain the data elements or put them into an array so I can use them as individual values.  I can't for the life of me work out how to do this.  For example, I need the value of `<PaymentReference>`

Can anyone assist?

Thanks

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
  ["GetPaymentsResult"]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (2) {
    ["schema"]=>
    string(1754) "<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="Payments"><xs:element name="Payments" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true"><xs:complexType><xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"><xs:element name="Payment"><xs:complexType><xs:sequence><xs:element name="PaymentID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/><xs:element name="EzidebitCustomerID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/><xs:element name="YourSystemReference" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/><xs:element name="YourGeneralReference" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/><xs:element name="CustomerName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/><xs:element name="DebitDate" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/><xs:element name="PaymentRef(erence" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/><xs:element name="PaymentMethod" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/><xs:element name="PaymentSource" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/><xs:element name="PaymentAmount" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/><xs:element name="SetupFee" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/><xs:element name="TransactionFeeClient" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/><xs:element name="TransactionFeeCustomer" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/><xs:element name="SettlementDate" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/><xs:element name="InvoiceID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/><xs:element name="PaymentStatus" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/><xs:element name="BankReturnCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/><xs:element name="BankFailedReason" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/><xs:element name="BankReceiptID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/><xs:element name="TransactionTime" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/></xs:sequence></xs:complexType></xs:element></xs:choice></xs:complexType></xs:element></xs:schema>"
    ["any"]=>
    string(6888) "<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"><Payments xmlns=""><Payment diffgr:id="Payment1" msdata:rowOrder="0"><PaymentID>2012_41393</PaymentID><EzidebitCustomerID>385943</EzidebitCustomerID><YourSystemReference>365</YourSystemReference><YourGeneralReference>365</YourGeneralReference><CustomerName>365</CustomerName><DebitDate>2012-02-20</DebitDate><PaymentReference>10922</PaymentReference><PaymentMethod>DR</PaymentMethod><PaymentSource>SCHEDULED</PaymentSource><PaymentAmount>118.65</PaymentAmount><SetupFee>3.30</SetupFee><TransactionFeeClient>1.10</TransactionFeeClient><TransactionFeeCustomer>0.00</TransactionFeeCustomer>
```

Comment: I assume you get the actual object back, and the var_dump is just for our enlightenment?

Comment: Can u paste the actual xml output from api call ?

Comment: Can you paste what you've tried that didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a `stdClass` object, you can access the values using object notation and you can use  [SimpleXML](http://php.net/simplexml) to parse the XML.  Here is an example:

```
$schema = $apiResult->GetPaymentsResult->schema;
$any    = $apiResult->GetPaymentsResult->any;

$xml    = new SimpleXmlElement($any);

echo $xml->Payments[0]->Payment->PaymentReference;
```

I'm not sure the `PaymentReference` is correct, but if you see the SimpleXml examples you should be able to figure it out pretty easily.

Comment: You're welcome, happy to help.  And welcome to SO, hopefully we can continue to be of assistance here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions. preg_match_all can help you. For example:

```
function preg_xa($r,$co,$n=1){
    $e=array();
    preg_match_all($r,$co,$m);
    for($i=0;$i<count($m[0]);$i++){
    $e[]=$m[$n][$i];
    }
    return $e;
}

function get_PaymentReference($content){
    return preg_xa( "/<PaymentReference>(.+)<\/PaymentReference>/simU", $content);
}
```

get_PaymentReference will return array of all values of PaymentReference tag.

Comment: And the second there are two PaymentReference elements in one response, this breaks.  At the very least, you'll want `(.+?)`, not `(.+)`.  Better, though, would be to use an XML parser.